# Flask submit form on POST: '405 Method not allowed'

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

Hi I am a bit confused about a flask application. I have a route `/ to welcomepage` that generates a `ux_uuid` then passes it to the form. Now, after I submit the form I want the ID (`ux_uuid`) passed on as well. However, in all cases (`form.validate==false` or even if all is ok) it ends up in a 405 error - Method not allowed. The `methods=['GET','POST']` has the `['POST']` method is there so I don't understand why even `if request.method == 'POST'` breaks?

app.py:

```
import logging, os
from flask import Flask, json, make_response, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from ux.forms import QuestionForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__,  static_url_path='')
app.secret_key = "NSA secret key"

csrf = CSRFProtect()
csrf.init_app(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcomepage():
    # Here is the random user ID generated by some random function but 
    # can be set to some string to test:
    ux_uuid = 'TETST_ID' #or set this to ux_uuid='TestUserID'
    return render_template('welcomepage.html', ux_uuid=ux_uuid)

@app.route('/form1/<ux_uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form1(ux_uuid):

    form = QuestionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            print("VALIDATE ME !")
            return render_template('/form1.html/<ux_uuid>', form=form, ux_uuid=ux_uuid)
        else:
            #
            #mylist = json.dumps(form.first_question)
            print('I STORED ALL THE FORM DATA IN THE SQLITE3 DB here - and GO ON TO:')
            return render_template('signup.html', ux_uuid=ux_uuid)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('form1.html', form=form, ux_uuid=ux_uuid)

    return render_template('form1.html')


# turn on debug=true to see error messages
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the /ux/forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectMultipleField, SubmitField, RadioField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length

class QuestionForm(Form):
    first_question = SelectMultipleField('What is your favourite food? Select all that apply:', choices=[('pizza','pizza'), ('more pizza', 'more pizza'), ('burger', 'burger'), ('salad', 'salad'), ('fries', 'fries'), ('pasta', 'pasta')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    second_question = RadioField('How many coins do you have?', choices=[('0','0'), ('1-5','1-5'), ('5-10','5-20'), ('More than 20', 'More than 20')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    third_question = RadioField('Do you like chocolate?', choices=[('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit & Continue')
```

and the form1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PREVIOUS EXPERIENCE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container signup-section">
      <div class="section-content">
        <h2>Please Answer the following questions</h2>

        <form method="POST" action="/form1">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.first_question.label }}

            {% if form.first_question.errors %}
              {% for error in form.first_question.errors %}
                <p class="error-message">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.first_question }}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.second_question.label }}

            {% if form.second_question.errors %}
              {% for error in form.second_question.errors %}
                <p class="error-message">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.second_question }}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.third_question.label }}

            {% if form.third_question.errors %}
              {% for error in form.third_question.errors %}
                <p class="error-message">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.third_question }}
          </div>

          {{ form.submit(class="btn-primary") }}
        </form>
      </div>
      <p>ID TEST:</p>
      {{ ux_uuid }}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the welcomepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WELCOMEPAGE</title>
  </head>
  <body><p> ENTRY PAGE / START WELCOME </p>
  <a href="{{url_for('form1', ux_uuid=ux_uuid)}}" class="btn btn-default">Continue</a></body>
</html>
```

Here are all files to test: [stack.zip](https://lillyallers.sharefile.com/d-s7eeaa2f84594ca1b)

Comment: What does your call look like?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by call? In my console I get this after submission of the form: [INFO] werkzeug 2017-07-20 14:27:22,912: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017 14:27:22] "GET /form1/SDQPMGyPqBmx4zej5RZ30 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[INFO] werkzeug 2017-07-20 14:27:30,610: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017 14:27:30] "POST /form1 HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Comment: Edit your question to add that detail in there. What I mean by call, is that you are trying to *talk* to your flask app by sending it a request. What is that request? It's *exact* structure. Whatever is making that call, your flask app is rejecting it. Seeing that call, will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you sending your post request to `welcomepage` or `form1`? the `welcomepage` does not seem to handle different types of requests

Comment: ok so there is what I do I go to 127.0.0.1:5000/welcomepage there is just some welcome text and a button to go to the form. Once I click on the button an ID ux_uuid is generated and passed to the form thats all that page is doing. Then I see the form fill in some text (radiobuttons etc) and on submission it saved this in the database and goes to /someotherpage still pushing the ux_uuid through (i hope). But if someone fails to fill all the required fields in the form form.validate() fails and should display the form again with ux_uuid and let them correct their entry etc.

Comment: Code edited with this example you should be able to replicate the 'Method not allowed' error. Also here are all files to test: [link](https://lillyallers.sharefile.com/d-s7eeaa2f84594ca1b)

Comment: Your html form is targetting `<form method="POST" action="/form1">`  you should be targetting `url_for('form1', ux_uuid=ux_uuid)`.  Likely the error is being raised by a catch-all route you have which is only accepting GET's.

Comment: Ok so to fix this I would have to `<form method="POST" action="url_for('form1', ux_uuid=ux_uuid)">` ? How would you write that?